# htaccess Directory browsing works only when subdir is present

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I did everything that should have been necessary to prevent directory browsing.

My `.htaccess` has this code: `Options All –Indexes`
It works fine when I browse into a directory where subdirs are present for example "example.net/system" "system" has subdirs like "main", "top" etc. But when I go into "example.net/system/main", in which no subdirs are present, I can see all php, html etc. files.

My .htaccess file is located in the /var/www/html folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I found a solution without .htaccess. For everybody who might have the same problem:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

then scroll down to:

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Direcotry>`

Now edit the `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` to `Options FollowSymLinks`

And btw `AllowOverride None` schould be `AllowOverride All` .

Then restart apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`